# Recovering Thunderbird mail from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, thunderbird, email

I had a laptop failure running Ubuntu. Fortunately HDD was intact. I installed Ubuntu on another laptop and can see all files when I attach this HDD as USB drive. I could thus recover most of my files except Thunderbird mail.

I am not a Linux or Ubuntu literate. Where is the mail kept which folder etc and how to copy across to new Thunderbird client please.
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

The thunderbird files is usually found under home. so in your external HDD it's `/home/USERNAME`

Profile folders are located here:

```
~/.thunderbird/
```

However, if you're using a third party build from  Ubuntu, those builds located here:

```
~/.mozilla-thunderbird/
```

use ctrl+h to view hidden files and search for one of the two dirs above.

Inside the dir you can find some dirs including your profile (Xxxxx.dedfault)

go inside you can find the dir Mail

[image]

go inside Mail and you can see your old mail files and can be imported to thunderbird

[image]